# Are all templates completely installed in my Windows Phone SDK 7.1?

Tags: windows-phone-7, winapi

i got an ebook from the net to learn windows phone developing 7.1 I was reading the book i saw this..that it was given a command to open the XNA Template but...

I realized the i see no more than 2 templates installed in my computer...

so does it mean that the windows phone SDK 7.1 is not properly installed in my pc?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install also **XNA SDK** -
[XNA SDK Download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23714)

Comment: but it comes with the SDK itself na?